# How to fetch data from multiple independent tables with no relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to extract data from multiple independent tables with no relationship .
Tables are tbl_temp1, tbl_temp2, tbl_temp3, tbl_temp4,so on
Every tables have common fields ie id,value,timestamp
But the records are independent in every tables so there is no relationship between them.

I want to generate values of all tables horizontally 
ie-
Value_of_tbl_temp1 | Value_of_tbl_temp2 | Value_of_tbl_temp3 | Value_of_tbl_temp4 | ...
             |              |              |              |

with no duplicates of data

Please help me with the solution.

Comment: but if you want to have results horizontally you must have relationship otherwise not possible change your table structure to create relationships

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT un.common_id, COALESCE(t1_value), COALESCE(t2_value), COALESCE(t3_value) FROM
(SELECT t1.common_id, t1.value as t1_value, NULL AS t2_value, NULL AS t3_value FROM t1
UNION 
SELECT t2.common_id, NULL, t2.value, NULL FROM t2
UNION 
SELECT t3.common_id, NULL, NULL, t3.value FROM t3) AS un
GROUP BY un.common_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If tables have common fields, then you can use UNION query to get data from all tables and then show them like you want.

Here is the mysql documentation page for UNION keyword:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: Thank you but with union records of all table will be shown vertically but I want it on horizontally

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
(SELECT value_of_tbl_temp1 FROM tbl_temp1 ORDER BY value_of_tbl_temp1 LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT value_of_tbl_temp2 FROM tbl_temp2 ORDER BY value_of_tbl_temp2 LIMIT 10)
..
```

rest you can refer [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

or 
You can simply select

```
select tbl1.value_of_tbl_temp1 as value_of_tbl_temp1,
tbl2.value_of_tbl_temp2 as value_of_tbl_temp2,
tbl3.value_of_tbl_temp3 as value_of_tbl_temp3,
tbl4.value_of_tbl_temp2 as value_of_tbl_temp4,
from 
tbl_temp1 as tbl1,
tbl_temp2 as tbl2,
tbl_temp3 as tbl3,
tbl_temp4 as tbl4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    tbl1.value as Value_of_tbl_temp1,
    tbl2.value as Value_of_tbl_temp2,
    tbl3.value as Value_of_tbl_temp3,
    tbl4.value as Value_of_tbl_temp4
FROM
    tbl_temp1 tbl1, 
    tbl_temp2 tbl2, 
    tbl_temp3 tbl3, 
    tbl_temp4 tbl4
```

Try this too.

```
SELECT
    tbl1.value AS Value_of_tbl_temp1,
    tbl2.value AS Value_of_tbl_temp2,
    tbl3.value AS Value_of_tbl_temp3,
    tbl4.value AS Value_of_tbl_temp4
FROM
(SELECT 
    VALUE,
    @rownum1:=@rownum1+1 rank
FROM
    tbl_temp1 tbl1, 
 (SELECT @rownum1:=0) r 
ORDER BY tbl1.id ASC) tbl1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    VALUE,
    @rownum2:=@rownum2+1 rank
FROM
    tbl_temp2 tbl2, 
     (SELECT @rownum2:=0) r 
ORDER BY tbl2.id ASC) tbl2
ON
tbl1.rank = tbl2.rank
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    VALUE,
    @rownum3:=@rownum3+1 rank
FROM
    tbl_temp3 tbl3, 
    (SELECT @rownum3:=0) r 
ORDER BY tbl3.id ASC) tbl3
ON
tbl1.rank = tbl3.rank
INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    VALUE,
    @rownum4:=@rownum4+1 rank
FROM
    tbl_temp4 tbl4, 
     (SELECT @rownum4:=0) r 
ORDER BY tbl2.id ASC) tbl4
ON
tbl1.rank = tbl4.rank
```

Comment: this is cartisian query and will produce a lot of undesired results

Comment: I tried this wil generate horizontally but at the same time generates the duplicate data